# Read an input file in shell script and store its lines in a variable

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to UNIX and have this really simple problem:

I have a text-file (input.txt) containing a string in each line. It looks like this:

```
House
Monkey
Car
```

And inside my shell script I need to read this input file line by line to get to a variable like this:

```
things="House,Monkey,Car"
```

I know this sounds easy, but I just couldnt find any simple solution for this. My closest attempt so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
things=""
addToString() {
    things="${things},$1"
}
while read line; do addToString $line ;done <input.txt
echo $things
```

But this won't work. Regarding to my google research I thought the while loop would create a new sub shell, but this I was wrong there (see the comment section). Nevertheless the variable "things" was still not available in the echo later on. (I cannot just write the echo inside the while loop, because I need to work with that string later on)

Could you please help me out here? Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This should work, just make sure to use quotes around your variables.

Comment: Well it does not, it just echos an empty string...

Comment: No, a while block does not create a subshell.

Comment: @Charles Duffy thank you for letting me know, it seemed that I maybe just misread this, I will change it in the question in about a second and will refer to your comment, thx ! +1

Comment: ...that said, if you're targeting bash 4.0 or newer, you might prefer to use `readarray` -- or, for an older version, an appropriate invocation of `read -a`. Both of those will read into arrays, not strings with comma-separated values, but transforming the former into the latter is trivial.

Comment: BTW, you might find BashFAQ #24 of interest (as it speaks in some detail to the problem you referred to... though your sample code here doesn't reproduce that problem): http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you proposed works fine! I've only made two changes here: Adding missing quotes, and handling the empty-string case.

```
things=""
addToString() {
    if [ -n "$things" ]; then
      things="${things},$1"
    else
      things="$1"
    fi
}
while read -r line; do addToString "$line"; done <input.txt
echo "$things"
```

If you were **piping** into `while read`, this would create a subshell, and that would eat your variables. You aren't piping -- you're doing a `<input.txt` redirection. No subshell, code works without changes.

---

That said, there are better ways to read lists of items into shell variables. On any version of bash after 3.0:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a things <input.txt  # read into an array
printf -v things_str '%s,' "${things[@]}"     # write array to a comma-separated string
echo "${things_str%,}"                        # print that string w/o trailing comma
```

...on bash 4, that first line can be:

```
readarray -t things <input.txt # read into an array
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You were right this works and also that only piping into a while creates a subshell (I mixed that up). In my headline of my script I used "#!/bin/sh" ... changing this to using the bash ("#!/bin/bash") the code I posted works fine. Also thank you for cleaning that code up adding missing quotes and handling the empty-string case, and also thanks for introducing alternative solutions on shells 3.0+

Comment: Changing `[[ $things ]]` to `[ -n "$things" ]` will make this work with `#!/bin/sh`. By the way, you might consider `read -r line` rather than `read line` on both shells -- otherwise, content read has backslash-escape sequences processed rather than handled literally.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a *shell* solution, but the truth is that solutions in pure shell are often excessively long and verbose. So e.g. to do string processing it is better to use special tools that are part of the “default” Unix environment.

```
sed ':b;N;$!bb;s/\n/,/g' < input.txt
```

If you want to omit empty lines, then:

```
sed ':b;N;$!bb;s/\n\n*/,/g' < input.txt
```

---

Speaking about your solution, it should work, but you should really always use quotes where applicable. E.g. this works for me:

```
things=""
while read line; do things="$things,$line"; done < input.txt
echo "$things"
```

(Of course, there is an issue with this code, as it outputs a leading comma. If you want to skip empty lines, just add an `if` check.)

Answer (score 0):

This might/might not work, depending on the shell you are using. On my Ubuntu 14.04/x64, it works with both `bash` and `dash`.

To make it more reliable and independent from the shell's behavior, you can try to put the whole block into a subshell explicitly, using the `()`. For example:

```
(
things=""
addToString() {
    things="${things},$1"
}
while read line; do addToString $line ;done 
echo $things
) < input.txt
```

P.S. You can use something like this to avoid the initial comma. Without bash extensions (using short-circuit logical operators instead of the `if` for shortness):

```
test -z "$things" && things="$1" || things="${things},${1}"
```

Or with bash extensions:

```
things="${things}${things:+,}${1}"
```

P.P.S. How I would have done it:

```
tr '\n' ',' < input.txt | sed 's!,$!\n!'
```

Comment: Why in the world are you creating a subshell, and thus throwing away the constructed variable? If you want to use grouping to scope the redirection, just use `{ ...; }`, not `( )`.

Comment: "Why in the world are you creating a subshell?" - Because it is simple enough to expain. And because I can do it by adding only two characters. And as a brute force tool, subshell is cleaner and straightforward.

Comment: `{` and `}` are also two characters, _and_ they allow `"$things"` to be used after the entire code segment is complete. Though why you'd redirect into the whole block rather than only the while loop is something I'm unclear on.

Comment: "why you'd redirect into the whole block" - why not? Inless I optimize for performance or I really need the value as variable, I rarely put data into variables. Sometimes I simply pipe things from one subshell to another, like `( ... ) | ( ... ) | ( ... )` which is a convenient paradigm for scalable batch data handling. People these days put too much data into the shell variables, instead of lettimg them flow through the pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r i
do
[[ $things == "" ]] && things="$i" || things="$things","$i"
done < <(grep . input.txt)
echo "$things"
```

Output:

```
House,Monkey,Car
```

> N.B:

Used `grep` to tackle with empty lines and the probability of not having a new line at the end of file. (Normal `while read` will fail to read the last line if there is no newline at the end of file.)

Comment: `arr=$(cat input.txt)` is misleading -- that's a string variable, not an array (and the more efficient way to read it would be `arr=$(<input.txt)`, if you _were_ going to read it as a string in that manner). Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: I'd also suggest checking what this code does when `input.txt` contains a line with only a literal `*`.

Comment: BTW, the grep is overkill. `while read -r i || [[ $i ]]; do` is a much more efficient way to solve handling of incomplete lines. (To be clear, a file lacking a trailing newline on its last line is _not_ a valid UNIX text file, so failing to read that last line is not necessarily an error).

Comment: It's just a precaution, even though it's a overkill. Not all the time the text file ends up with a trailing new line.

Comment: Sure. But if you're going to take the precaution, it's still better to take the version of that precaution that doesn't require an extra fork/exec and pipeline element (thus, extra `read()` and `write()` calls for all content processed).